# Pandas Split a Column by Multiple delimiters into same column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split

I have a pandas dataframe of multiple columns. But the Column of interest say is Col A which looks like :

```
      dfInput

               A 

       12 - ksjksu,nsusi,9018,1.00uy,9.0Vm,+/ - 20%(0.22suns); 891- 1o19jsksuisolslskosBN
       205 - lksiosslsoujhs%ysus(0.33mismsn);31 - jsks,msnu
       22 - 0204 - 2762.0uhsyuskis;14 - gnshj,msuis,lsolso2.2n; 67181 - iuwuwiwi
```

So my goal is to split the strings into 2 parts one by the first '-' before/after the semicolon and then by the rest where the first column will have all the numbers on the left of first '-' and then the other column will have rest . So my output dataframe should look like:

```
        **dfOutDesired**

           B                                          C
         12 891    ksjksu,nsusi,9018,1.00uy,9.0Vm,+/ - 20%(0.22suns) 1o19jsksuisolslskosBN
         205 31    lksiosslsoujhs%ysus(0.33mismsn)  jsks,msnu
         22 14 67181  0204 - 2762.0uhsyuskis gnshj,msuis,lsolso2.2n iuwuwiwi
```

So till now I have tried the following based on earlier posts I saw:

```
      df['C'] =    df["A"].str.replace(r'\w+\s*-\s*', '', regex=True)

      df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(' ', '')
      df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace('-', ' - ')

      df["B"] = df["A"].str.replace(r'\s*;\s*\S+;+\S+;+\s*', ' ', regex=True).str.strip()
```

So I am getting partially correct output for Col C (where say 0204 in third row is not picked up) , but for Col B I am just getting the same Col A  as follows:

```
       **mydfWrong**

                                B     
       12 - ksjksu,nsusi,9018,1.00uy,9.0Vm,+/ - 20%(0.22suns); 891- 1o19jsksuisolslskosBN
       205 - lksiosslsoujhs%ysus(0.33mismsn);31 - jsks,msnu
       22 - 0204 - 2762.0uhsyuskis;14 - gnshj,msuis,lsolso2.2n; 67181 - iuwuwiwi

                               C

            ksjksu,nsusi,9018,1.00uy,9.0Vm,+/ - 20%(0.22suns) 1o19jsksuisolslskosBN
            lksiosslsoujhs%ysus(0.33mismsn)  jsks,msnu
            2762.0uhsyuskis gnshj,msuis,lsolso2.2n iuwuwiwi
```

Not sure how to use the regex properly in this case. So any help will be immensely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with something like the following.

The `get_nums` function splits on the `;`, then removes the integers based on the specified conditions

The `get_the_rest` function does the opposite, and substitutes those values with empty spaces

```
def get_nums(x):
    return " ".join([re.search(r'^[0-9]+', y.strip()).group() for y in x.split(";")])

def get_the_rest(x):
    return "".join([re.sub(r'[0-9]+\s?\-', '', y.strip()) for y in x.split(";")])

df["B"] = df["A"].apply(lambda x: get_nums(x))
df["C"] = df["A"].apply(lambda x: get_the_rest(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single regex call to `findall` and then grab only the necessary data:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['205 - lksiosslsoujhs%ysus(0.33mismsn);31 - jsks,msnu', '22 - 0204 - 2762.0uhsyuskis;14 - gnshj,msuis,lsolso2.2n; 67181 - iuwuwiwi']})

rx = r'(\d+)\s*-\s*(.*?)(?=;\s*\d|$)' # Define the regex
m = df['A'].str.findall(rx)         # Get all matches and captures
df["B"] = m.apply(lambda x: " ".join(c[0] for c in x)) # Join Group 1 values into Column B
df["C"] = m.apply(lambda x: " ".join(c[1] for c in x)) # Join Group 1 values into Column C
```

Output:

```
>>> print(df.to_string())
                                                                            A            B                                                       C
0                       205 - lksiosslsoujhs%ysus(0.33mismsn);31 - jsks,msnu       205 31               lksiosslsoujhs%ysus(0.33mismsn) jsks,msnu
1  22 - 0204 - 2762.0uhsyuskis;14 - gnshj,msuis,lsolso2.2n; 67181 - iuwuwiwi  22 14 67181  0204 - 2762.0uhsyuskis gnshj,msuis,lsolso2.2n iuwuwiwi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OI3Tn9/2) that matches

- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\s*-\s*` - a `-` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=;\s*\d|$)`  - positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with `;` + zero or more whitespaces and then a digit, or end of string.

Comment: Wondeful!  This one works too!